# Writing a Stack Exchange chat application in GTK+ 3, what should I use to display messages?

Tags: linux, gtk, chat, gtk3, stackexchange

I am writing an application for Stack Exchange chat using GTK+ 3. I was wondering what components are generally used and recommended to use for actually displaying messages.

My options right now are WebKit (for easy HTML rendering), a GtkListBox (for easy list management), or something else. What would be the best choice to make in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Adding potentially tens of thousands of widgets (in the case of a ListBox) is usually not a great idea. Take a look at the [text widgets](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/TextWidget.html) (TextView, TextBuffer, etc): The powerful formatting gives you quite a lot rendering possibilities and it'll perform fairly well even with tens of thousands of messages. See [chatview](https://git.gnome.org/browse/polari/tree/src/chatView.js) in Polari IRC client for an example (also [screenshots](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Polari/)).

Comment: I don't think the TextBuffer/TextView will work because this is Stack Exchange chat and I need to handle starring/editing/flags/etc.

Comment: Well, without actual requirements this is too broad to answer. The TextBuffer tags are more powerful than they seem though. As an example many parts of the polari TextView are clickable. E.g. clicking a nick will show a popover that has more UI related to the user. Also it's possible to add child widgets, like GtkImages or GtkButtons, into the text view (see e.g. gtk_text_view_add_child_at_anchor()).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a Treeview ? A [Treeview](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html) and a [ListStore](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GListStore.html) are pretty easy to setup and manage and have all the capabilities of a Listbox in your case.

Comment: I think this is misleading. A treeview does not have the capabilities of a standard container like ListBox.

Comment: @jku Note that I said *in your case*. If I read the question right, it was asked how to render a message. A Treeview and Liststore are quite adequate for this purpose when you use a CellRendererText https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCellRendererText.html.